# Can't update GRUB

Tags: ubuntu, grub

Rebooted my server running Ubuntu 16.04 yesterday and since then I have been unable to update GRUB.

```
sudo update-grub 
Generating grub configuration file ...
grub-probe: error: not a directory.

sudo grub-probe -vvv -d /dev/sda1 -t fs       
grub-probe: info: adding `hd0' -> `/dev/sda' from device.map.
grub-probe: info: adding `hd1' -> `/dev/sdb' from device.map.
grub-probe: info: adding `hd2' -> `/dev/sdc' from device.map.
grub-probe: info: adding `hd3' -> `/dev/sdd' from device.map.
grub-probe: info: /dev/sda1 is present.
grub-probe: info: Looking for /dev/sda1.
grub-probe: info: /dev/sda is a parent of /dev/sda1.
grub-probe: info: /dev/sda1 starts from 2048.
grub-probe: info: opening the device hd0.
grub-core/kern/disk.c:196: Opening `hd0'...
grub-probe: info: drive = 0.
grub-probe: info: the size of hd0 is 234441648.
grub-core/kern/disk.c:196: Opening `hd0'...
grub-probe: info: drive = 0.
grub-probe: info: the size of hd0 is 234441648.
grub-core/disk/diskfilter.c:135: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hd0
grub-probe: info: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid1x devices on disk hd0.
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:415: opening the device `/dev/sda' in open_device()
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:394: reusing open device `/dev/sda'
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:394: reusing open device `/dev/sda'
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09 devices on disk hd0.
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:394: reusing open device `/dev/sda'
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09_be devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for dmraid_nv devices on disk hd0.
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:394: reusing open device `/dev/sda'
grub-probe: info: Scanning for ldm devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: scanning hd0 for LDM.
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 0: flag 0x80, type 0x83, start 0x800, len 0x3200000
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 1: flag 0x0, type 0x83, start 0x3200800, len 0x5a00000
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 2: flag 0x0, type 0x82, start 0xd793000, len 0x800000
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 3: flag 0x0, type 0x0, start 0x0, len 0x0
grub-probe: info: no LDM signature found.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for lvm devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: no LVM signature found.
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 0: flag 0x80, type 0x83, start 0x800, len 0x3200000
grub-core/disk/diskfilter.c:135: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hd0
grub-probe: info: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid1x devices on disk hd0.
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:415: opening the device `/dev/sda1' in open_device()
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:394: reusing open device `/dev/sda1'
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09 devices on disk hd0.
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:394: reusing open device `/dev/sda1'
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09_be devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for dmraid_nv devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for ldm devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: scanning hd0 for LDM.
grub-probe: info: no LDM signature found.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for lvm devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: no LVM signature found.
grub-core/partmap/dfly.c:72: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0xc4464c59)
grub-core/partmap/apple.c:123: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0x4552)
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 1: flag 0x0, type 0x83, start 0x3200800, len 0x5a00000
grub-core/disk/diskfilter.c:135: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hd0
grub-probe: info: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid1x devices on disk hd0.
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:415: opening the device `/dev/sda2' in open_device()
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:394: reusing open device `/dev/sda2'
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09 devices on disk hd0.
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:394: reusing open device `/dev/sda2'
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09_be devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for dmraid_nv devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for ldm devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: scanning hd0 for LDM.
grub-probe: info: no LDM signature found.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for lvm devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: no LVM signature found.
grub-core/partmap/dfly.c:72: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0xc4464c59)
grub-core/partmap/apple.c:123: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0x4552)
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 2: flag 0x0, type 0x82, start 0xd793000, len 0x800000
grub-core/disk/diskfilter.c:135: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hd0
grub-probe: info: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid1x devices on disk hd0.
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:415: opening the device `/dev/sda3' in open_device()
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:394: reusing open device `/dev/sda3'
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09 devices on disk hd0.
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:394: reusing open device `/dev/sda3'
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09_be devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for dmraid_nv devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for ldm devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: scanning hd0 for LDM.
grub-probe: info: no LDM signature found.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for lvm devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: no LVM signature found.
grub-core/partmap/dfly.c:72: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0xc4464c59)
grub-core/partmap/apple.c:123: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0x4552)
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 3: flag 0x0, type 0x0, start 0x0, len 0x0
grub-core/partmap/dfly.c:72: bad magic (found 0x128e852; wanted 0xc4464c59)
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 0: flag 0x80, type 0x83, start 0x800, len 0x3200000
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 1: flag 0x0, type 0x83, start 0x3200800, len 0x5a00000
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 2: flag 0x0, type 0x82, start 0xd793000, len 0x800000
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 3: flag 0x0, type 0x0, start 0x0, len 0x0
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 0: flag 0x80, type 0x83, start 0x800, len 0x3200000
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 1: flag 0x0, type 0x83, start 0x3200800, len 0x5a00000
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 2: flag 0x0, type 0x82, start 0xd793000, len 0x800000
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 3: flag 0x0, type 0x0, start 0x0, len 0x0
grub-core/partmap/apple.c:123: bad magic (found 0xeb63; wanted 0x4552)
grub-core/kern/disk.c:295: Closing `hd0'.
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 0: flag 0x80, type 0x83, start 0x800, len 0x3200000
grub-probe: info: Partition 0 starts from 2048.
grub-core/kern/disk.c:295: Closing `hd0'.
grub-probe: info: /dev/sda1 is present.
grub-probe: info: Looking for /dev/sda1.
grub-probe: info: /dev/sda is a parent of /dev/sda1.
grub-probe: info: /dev/sda1 starts from 2048.
grub-probe: info: opening the device hd0.
grub-core/kern/disk.c:196: Opening `hd0'...
grub-probe: info: drive = 0.
grub-probe: info: the size of hd0 is 234441648.
grub-core/kern/disk.c:196: Opening `hd0'...
grub-probe: info: drive = 0.
grub-probe: info: the size of hd0 is 234441648.
grub-core/disk/diskfilter.c:135: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hd0
grub-probe: info: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid1x devices on disk hd0.
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:415: opening the device `/dev/sda' in open_device()
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09 devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09_be devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for dmraid_nv devices on disk hd0.
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:394: reusing open device `/dev/sda'
grub-probe: info: Scanning for ldm devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: scanning hd0 for LDM.
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 0: flag 0x80, type 0x83, start 0x800, len 0x3200000
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 1: flag 0x0, type 0x83, start 0x3200800, len 0x5a00000
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 2: flag 0x0, type 0x82, start 0xd793000, len 0x800000
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 3: flag 0x0, type 0x0, start 0x0, len 0x0
grub-probe: info: no LDM signature found.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for lvm devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: no LVM signature found.
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 0: flag 0x80, type 0x83, start 0x800, len 0x3200000
grub-core/disk/diskfilter.c:135: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hd0
grub-probe: info: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid1x devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09 devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09_be devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for dmraid_nv devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for ldm devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: scanning hd0 for LDM.
grub-probe: info: no LDM signature found.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for lvm devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: no LVM signature found.
grub-core/partmap/dfly.c:72: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0xc4464c59)
grub-core/partmap/apple.c:123: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0x4552)
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 1: flag 0x0, type 0x83, start 0x3200800, len 0x5a00000
grub-core/disk/diskfilter.c:135: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hd0
grub-probe: info: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid1x devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09 devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09_be devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for dmraid_nv devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for ldm devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: scanning hd0 for LDM.
grub-probe: info: no LDM signature found.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for lvm devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: no LVM signature found.
grub-core/partmap/dfly.c:72: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0xc4464c59)
grub-core/partmap/apple.c:123: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0x4552)
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 2: flag 0x0, type 0x82, start 0xd793000, len 0x800000
grub-core/disk/diskfilter.c:135: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hd0
grub-probe: info: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid1x devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09 devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09_be devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for dmraid_nv devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for ldm devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: scanning hd0 for LDM.
grub-probe: info: no LDM signature found.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for lvm devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: no LVM signature found.
grub-core/partmap/dfly.c:72: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0xc4464c59)
grub-core/partmap/apple.c:123: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0x4552)
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 3: flag 0x0, type 0x0, start 0x0, len 0x0
grub-core/partmap/dfly.c:72: bad magic (found 0x128e852; wanted 0xc4464c59)
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 0: flag 0x80, type 0x83, start 0x800, len 0x3200000
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 1: flag 0x0, type 0x83, start 0x3200800, len 0x5a00000
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 2: flag 0x0, type 0x82, start 0xd793000, len 0x800000
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 3: flag 0x0, type 0x0, start 0x0, len 0x0
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 0: flag 0x80, type 0x83, start 0x800, len 0x3200000
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 1: flag 0x0, type 0x83, start 0x3200800, len 0x5a00000
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 2: flag 0x0, type 0x82, start 0xd793000, len 0x800000
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 3: flag 0x0, type 0x0, start 0x0, len 0x0
grub-core/partmap/apple.c:123: bad magic (found 0xeb63; wanted 0x4552)
grub-core/kern/disk.c:295: Closing `hd0'.
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 0: flag 0x80, type 0x83, start 0x800, len 0x3200000
grub-probe: info: Partition 0 starts from 2048.
grub-core/kern/disk.c:295: Closing `hd0'.
grub-probe: info: /dev/sda1 is present.
grub-probe: info: Looking for /dev/sda1.
grub-probe: info: /dev/sda is a parent of /dev/sda1.
grub-probe: info: /dev/sda1 starts from 2048.
grub-probe: info: opening the device hd0.
grub-core/kern/disk.c:196: Opening `hd0'...
grub-probe: info: drive = 0.
grub-probe: info: the size of hd0 is 234441648.
grub-core/kern/disk.c:196: Opening `hd0'...
grub-probe: info: drive = 0.
grub-probe: info: the size of hd0 is 234441648.
grub-core/disk/diskfilter.c:135: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hd0
grub-probe: info: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid1x devices on disk hd0.
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:415: opening the device `/dev/sda' in open_device()
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09 devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09_be devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for dmraid_nv devices on disk hd0.
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:394: reusing open device `/dev/sda'
grub-probe: info: Scanning for ldm devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: scanning hd0 for LDM.
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 0: flag 0x80, type 0x83, start 0x800, len 0x3200000
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 1: flag 0x0, type 0x83, start 0x3200800, len 0x5a00000
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 2: flag 0x0, type 0x82, start 0xd793000, len 0x800000
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 3: flag 0x0, type 0x0, start 0x0, len 0x0
grub-probe: info: no LDM signature found.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for lvm devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: no LVM signature found.
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 0: flag 0x80, type 0x83, start 0x800, len 0x3200000
grub-core/disk/diskfilter.c:135: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hd0
grub-probe: info: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid1x devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09 devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09_be devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for dmraid_nv devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for ldm devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: scanning hd0 for LDM.
grub-probe: info: no LDM signature found.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for lvm devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: no LVM signature found.
grub-core/partmap/dfly.c:72: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0xc4464c59)
grub-core/partmap/apple.c:123: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0x4552)
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 1: flag 0x0, type 0x83, start 0x3200800, len 0x5a00000
grub-core/disk/diskfilter.c:135: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hd0
grub-probe: info: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid1x devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09 devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09_be devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for dmraid_nv devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for ldm devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: scanning hd0 for LDM.
grub-probe: info: no LDM signature found.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for lvm devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: no LVM signature found.
grub-core/partmap/dfly.c:72: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0xc4464c59)
grub-core/partmap/apple.c:123: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0x4552)
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 2: flag 0x0, type 0x82, start 0xd793000, len 0x800000
grub-core/disk/diskfilter.c:135: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hd0
grub-probe: info: Scanning for DISKFILTER devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid1x devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09 devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for mdraid09_be devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for dmraid_nv devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for ldm devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: scanning hd0 for LDM.
grub-probe: info: no LDM signature found.
grub-probe: info: Scanning for lvm devices on disk hd0.
grub-probe: info: no LVM signature found.
grub-core/partmap/dfly.c:72: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0xc4464c59)
grub-core/partmap/apple.c:123: bad magic (found 0x0; wanted 0x4552)
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 3: flag 0x0, type 0x0, start 0x0, len 0x0
grub-core/partmap/dfly.c:72: bad magic (found 0x128e852; wanted 0xc4464c59)
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 0: flag 0x80, type 0x83, start 0x800, len 0x3200000
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 1: flag 0x0, type 0x83, start 0x3200800, len 0x5a00000
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 2: flag 0x0, type 0x82, start 0xd793000, len 0x800000
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 3: flag 0x0, type 0x0, start 0x0, len 0x0
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 0: flag 0x80, type 0x83, start 0x800, len 0x3200000
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 1: flag 0x0, type 0x83, start 0x3200800, len 0x5a00000
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 2: flag 0x0, type 0x82, start 0xd793000, len 0x800000
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 3: flag 0x0, type 0x0, start 0x0, len 0x0
grub-core/partmap/apple.c:123: bad magic (found 0xeb63; wanted 0x4552)
grub-core/kern/disk.c:295: Closing `hd0'.
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 0: flag 0x80, type 0x83, start 0x800, len 0x3200000
grub-probe: info: Partition 0 starts from 2048.
grub-core/kern/disk.c:295: Closing `hd0'.
grub-probe: info: opening hd0,msdos1.
grub-core/kern/disk.c:196: Opening `hd0,msdos1'...
grub-probe: info: drive = 0.
grub-probe: info: the size of hd0 is 234441648.
grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:188: partition 0: flag 0x80, type 0x83, start 0x800, len 0x3200000
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting zfs...
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:415: opening the device `/dev/sda1' in open_device()
grub-core/fs/zfs/zfs.c:1192: label ok 0
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:394: reusing open device `/dev/sda1'
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:394: reusing open device `/dev/sda1'
grub-core/fs/zfs/zfs.c:1192: label ok 1
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:394: reusing open device `/dev/sda1'
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:394: reusing open device `/dev/sda1'
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:394: reusing open device `/dev/sda1'
grub-core/fs/zfs/zfs.c:1192: label ok 2
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:394: reusing open device `/dev/sda1'
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:394: reusing open device `/dev/sda1'
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:394: reusing open device `/dev/sda1'
grub-core/fs/zfs/zfs.c:1192: label ok 3
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:394: reusing open device `/dev/sda1'
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:394: reusing open device `/dev/sda1'
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: zfs detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting xfs...
grub-core/fs/xfs.c:887: Reading sb
grub-core/fs/xfs.c:243: Validating superblock
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: xfs detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting ufs2...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: ufs2 detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting ufs1_be...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: ufs1_be detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting ufs1...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: ufs1 detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting udf...
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:394: reusing open device `/dev/sda1'
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:394: reusing open device `/dev/sda1'
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:394: reusing open device `/dev/sda1'
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: udf detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting tarfs...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: tarfs detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting squash4...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: squash4 detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting sfs...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: sfs detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting romfs...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: romfs detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting reiserfs...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: reiserfs detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting procfs...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: procfs detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting odc...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: odc detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting ntfs...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: ntfs detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting nilfs2...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: nilfs2 detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting newc...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: newc detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting minix_be...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: minix_be detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting minix3_be...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: minix3_be detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting minix3...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: minix3 detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting minix2_be...
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: minix2_be detection failed.
grub-core/kern/fs.c:56: Detecting minix2...
grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:394: reusing open device `/dev/sda1'
grub-core/kern/fs.c:78: minix2 detection failed.
grub-probe: error: not a directory.
```